# Filter date with time

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to filter one of the columns where I need to filter date (it has to be today´s date or a specific date) and hour has to be greater than 7 am and smaller than 19 pm.

My data set looks like this: 2023/03/17 16:00

I am trying to use the following code:

```
Sub FilterInicioDeTurnoDAY()
Dim in_time As Double, out_time As Double, dtToday As Date

dtToday = Date
in_time = dtToday + TimeValue("07:00")
out_time = dtToday + TimeValue("18:59")


 Sheets("PegarCitas_INICIOdeTURNO").Select
 
 ActiveSheet.Range("E:E").AutoFilter Field:=34, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria1:=">=" & in_time, Criteria2:="<=" & out_time

End Sub
```

However when I run the macro it does not filter the values I need. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub FilterByDateTime()
Dim in_time As Double, out_time As Double, dtToday As Date
Dim in_timed, out_timed
dtToday = Date
in_time = dtToday + TimeValue("07:00")
out_time = dtToday + TimeValue("18:59")
in_timed = DateSerial(Year(in_time), Month(in_time), Day(in_time)) + TimeSerial(Hour(in_time), Minute(in_time), Second(in_time))
out_timed = DateSerial(Year(out_time), Month(out_time), Day(out_time)) + TimeSerial(Hour(out_time), Minute(out_time), Second(out_time))
Sheets("PegarCitas_INICIOdeTURNO").Range("E:E").EntireColumn.AutoFilter Field:=34, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria1:=">=" & in_timed, Criteria2:="<=" & out_timed
End Sub
```

Also avoid using select since most things can be without selecting cells.

Edit - Turns out the dates being passed to the filter need to be in the US format according to [this article](https://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/autofilter-vba-dates.htm). If not, the filtering won't work.

Comment: Hi Mihir, it appears "run time error "13" - type mismatch" on the line which starts with out time

Comment: @BrunoTavares Edited and tested, this code should work for you

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub FilterInicioDeTurnoDAY()
   Dim in_time As Double, out_time As Double, dtToday As Date
   
   dtToday = Date
   in_time = dtToday + TimeValue("07:00")
   out_time = dtToday + TimeValue("18:59")
   Me.Range("E:E").AutoFilter Field:=34, Operator:=xlAnd, _
                   Criteria1:=">=" & Format(in_time, "yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm"), _
                   Criteria2:="<=" & Format(out_time, "yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm")
End Sub
```